# Htoi incorrect output at 10 digits

Tags: c++, string, function, hex, decimal

When I input
0x123456789
I get incorrect outputs, I can't figure out why. At first I thought it was a max possible int value problem, but I changed my variables to unsigned long and the problem was still there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long htoi(char s[]);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Hex \n";
    char hexstring[20];
    cin >> hexstring;
    cout << htoi(hexstring) << "\n";

}

//Converts string to hex
long htoi(char s[])
{
    int charsize = 0;
    while (s[charsize] != '\0')
    {
        charsize++;
    }
    int base = 1;
    unsigned long total = 0;
    unsigned long multiplier = 1;
    for (int i = charsize; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X' || s[i] == '\0')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if ( (s[i] >= '0') && (s[i] <= '9') )
        {
            total = total + ((s[i] - '0') * multiplier);
            multiplier = multiplier * 16UL;
            continue;
        }
        if ((s[i] >= 'A') && (s[i] <= 'F'))
        {
            total = total + ((s[i] - '7') * multiplier); //'7' equals 55 in decimal, while 'A' equals 65
            multiplier = multiplier * 16UL;
            continue;
        }
        if ((s[i] >= 'a') && (s[i] <= 'f'))
        {
            total = total + ((s[i] - 'W') * multiplier); //W equals 87 in decimal, while 'a' equals 97
            multiplier = multiplier * 16UL;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger or print statements. You know what you expect at every line. Check it against what the value actually is.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, though, you are doing it backwards. Start with the _first_ digit, combine it with your result (`total`), then multiply by 16. Repeat until you are out of numbers. BTW, you'll have an issue if you use signed numbers. Use an `_unsigned_ long long`.

Comment: @Duthomhas It is easier if it is done backwards because hex is read from right to left. If I read left to right, I will need to re-write my code to where multiplier starts by the highest power (powered by the number of hex digits), and divide by 16 each time a hex character is read. Also the multiplier would be divided unnecessarily when the user inputs hex in the form: 0xABCDEFG because 0 is a hex character, which would then complicate my code to ignore the first two characters if 0x are in sequential order. Reading backwards would be easiest and most efficient way to write this (see sol).

Comment: You had to ask us how to make it happen but somehow you know better how to do it? That's funny, because I can do it in three lines of code. Hint: while you are learning, don't assume you understand things better than others. And BTW, just like _any_ number, hex is read left-to-right; most-to-least significant.

Comment: @Duthomhas I apologize if I made you feel as you were discredited, that was not my intention. I understand I am a beginner, so I do not believe that I understand code any better than anyone else. I think it would be interesting to see your example converting hex to int in three lines without using the pre-written parsers in the C/C++ library hence the strtol function. I am always open to further my knowledge. I couldn't find anywhere that hex is strictly read left to right though because I've seen it taught both ways, but I do enjoy the idea of most-to-least significant.

Comment: @TommySaechao I did not feel bad. I just wanted you to realize that you were missing something. I am, truthfully, pleased that you worked out a solution by yourself -- it was a good one. I was only bothered that you seed to blithely discredit a suggestion designed to help you understand the problem better. My wording is sometimes too curt, though, and I am sorry for that. I have, at your request, posted a complete solution below that works left to right. :O)

Answer (score 2):

`long` probably is 32 bits on your computer as well. Try `long long`.

Answer (score 2):

You need more than 32 bits to store that number. Your long type could well be as small as 32 bits.

Use a std::uint64_t instead. This is always a 64 bit unsigned type. If your compiler doesn't support that, use a long long. That must be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The idea follows the polynomial nature of a number. 123 is the same as

1*10<sup>2</sup> + 2*10<sup>1</sup> + 3*10<sup>0</sup>

In other words, I had to multiply the first digit by ten *two times*. I had to multiply 2 by ten *one time*. And I multiplied the last digit by one. Again, reading from left to right:

- Multiply zero by ten and add the 1 → 0*10+1 = 1.
- Multiply that by ten and add the 2 → 1*10+2 = 12.
- Multiply that by ten and add the 3 → 12*10+3 = 123.

We will do the same thing:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long hextodec( const std::string& s )
{
  unsigned long long result = 0;
  for (char c : s)
  {
    result *= 16;
    if (isdigit( c )) result |= c - '0';
    else              result |= toupper( c ) - 'A' + 10;
  }
  return result;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  cout << hextodec( argv[1] ) << "\n";
}
```

You may notice that the function is more than three lines. I did that for clarity. C++ idioms can make that loop a single line:

```
for (char c : s)
  result = (result << 4) | (isdigit( c ) ? (c - '0') : (toupper( c ) - 'A' + 10));
```

You can also do validation if you like. What I have presented *is not the only way* to do the digit-to-value conversion. There exist other methods that are just as good (and some that are better).

I do hope this helps.

Comment: That's actually really remarkable how you shortened the code almost entirely using idioms. How would you write it if you wanted to ignore the "0x" part of the string passed into the function?

Comment: `if (s.size()>2 and s[0]=='0' and std::toupper(s[1])=='X') return hextodec(s.substr(2));`

Comment: Or `if (toupper(s).find("0X") == 0) return hextodec(s.substr(2));` (where toupper() is a custom function taking a string). There are many ways.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening, when I inputted "1234567890" it would skip over the '0' so I had to modify the code. The other problem was that long was indeed 32-bits, so I changed it to uint64_t as suggested by @Bathsheba. Here's the final working code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

uint64_t htoi(char s[]);

int main()
{
    char hexstring[20];
    cin >> hexstring;
    cout << htoi(hexstring) << "\n";

}

//Converts string to hex
uint64_t htoi(char s[])
{
    int charsize = 0;
    while (s[charsize] != '\0')
    {
        charsize++;
    }
    int base = 1;
    uint64_t total = 0;
    uint64_t multiplier = 1;
    for (int i = charsize; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X' || s[i] == '\0')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if ( (s[i] >= '0') && (s[i] <= '9') )
        {
            total = total + ((uint64_t)(s[i] - '0') * multiplier);
            multiplier = multiplier * 16;
            continue;
        }
        if ((s[i] >= 'A') && (s[i] <= 'F'))
        {
            total = total + ((uint64_t)(s[i] - '7') * multiplier); //'7' equals 55 in decimal, while 'A' equals 65
            multiplier = multiplier * 16;
            continue;
        }
        if ((s[i] >= 'a') && (s[i] <= 'f'))
        {
            total = total + ((uint64_t)(s[i] - 'W') * multiplier); //W equals 87 in decimal, while 'a' equals 97
            multiplier = multiplier * 16;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```